# Get info about function application operator

Tags: haskell, operators, ghci

In `GHCI` you can get info about all kinds of stuff like

```
Prelude> :i map
map :: (a -> b) -> [a] -> [b]   -- Defined in `GHC.Base'
Prelude> :i (+)
class Num a where
  (+) :: a -> a -> a
  ...
        -- Defined in `GHC.Num'
infixl 6 +
Prelude> :i :
data [] a = ... | a : [a]       -- Defined in `GHC.Types'
infixr 5 :
```

I read something like "function application has the highest precedence" which means

```
f "hello" * g 'w'
```

is equivalent to

```
(f "hello") * (g 'w')
```

Can I get info about function application? Is it a actual operator?

The following does *not* work

```
Prelude> :i ( )

<interactive>:1:2: error:
    parse error (possibly incorrect indentation or mismatched brackets)
Prelude>
```

Comment: Maybe this `:i (->)`?

Comment: No, application is not an actual operator. Otherwise you would need to _apply_ it to its arguments, going in circles. There's `($)` which does the same thing and is an actual operator, though.

Comment: @FrankSimon While `:i (->)` has nothing to do with function application, the result is interesting to read. For beginners. Like me. I interpret it as "`->` is the `function` type".

Comment: @chi Accepted as an answer. ;-)